# Error while trying to load a JSON object with python 3

Tags: python, json

I have the following json object I am trying to parse with python 3:

```
customerData = {   
 "Joe": {"visits": 1},  
 "Carol":  {"visits": 2},  
 "Howard": {"visits": 3},  
 "Carrie": {"visits": 4}  
}
```

I am using the following python code to parse the object:

```
import json 

def greetCustomer(customerData):
    response = json.loads(customerData)
```

I'm getting the following error:

> TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'dict'

Comment: That's not a JSON object; it's a fragment of Python code. `customerData` is *already* a dict, which is what you would be using `json.loads` to produce.

Comment: `customerData` already _is_ a dictionary?

Comment: Do you mean you're trying to turn it _into_ a JSON string? Then you need to go in the other direction: `json.dumps()`

Comment: @chepner Are you saying that I can use the data as is? Just treat it as I would a python dict?

Comment: Yes, because it *is* a Python dict, which is what the error message is telling you. JSON is just a language-independent string encoding of common data structures. The fact that the syntax is very similar to native Python syntax can be a source of confusion. (See the end of my answer for examples of things that are valid Python but not valid JSON and vice versa.)

Comment: @chepner, That was the problem!! I didn't realize that JSON and python dict were similar.... I can treat the object as a dictionary

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
customerData = {   
 "Joe": {"visits": 1},  
 "Carol":  {"visits": 2},  
 "Howard": {"visits": 3},  
 "Carrie": {"visits": 4}  
}
```

is Python code that defines a dictionary. If you had

```
customerJSON = """{   
 "Joe": {"visits": 1},  
 "Carol":  {"visits": 2},  
 "Howard": {"visits": 3},  
 "Carrie": {"visits": 4}  
}"""
```

you would have a string that contains a JSON object to be parsed. (Yes, there is a lot of overlap between Python syntax and JSON syntax.

```
assert customerData == json.loads(customerJSON)
```

would pass.)

---

Note, though, that not *all* valid Python resembles valid JSON.

Here are three different JSON strings that encode the same object:

```
json_strs = [
 "{'foo': 'bar'}",  # invalid JSON, uses single quotes
 '{"foo": "bar"}',  # valid JSON, uses double quotes
 '{foo: "bar"}'     # valid JSON, quotes around key can be omitted
]
```

You can observe that `all(json.loads(x) == {'foo': 'bar'} for x in json_strs)` is true, since all three strings encode the same Python dict.

Conversely, we can define three Python dicts, the first two of which are identical.

```
json_str = json_strs[0]  # Just to pick one
foo = ...  # Some value
dicts = [
  {'foo': 'bar'},     # valid Python dict
  {"foo": "bar"},     # valid Python dict
  {foo: "bar"}        # valid Python dict *if* foo is a hashable value
                      # and not necessarily 
]
```

It is true that `dicts[0] == dicts[1] == json.loads(json_str)`. However,
`dicts[2] == json.loads(json_str)` is only true if `foo == "foo"`.

Answer (score 15):

You seem to be mistaking load and dump.

`json.loads` converts a string to a python object, `json.load` converts a json file into a python object whereas `json.dumps` converts a python object to a string and `json.dump` writes a json string to a file from a python object

*Tip*: notice that `loads` and `dumps` have an **s** at the end, as in **string**